# how can i save data, retrieved from a url into my database

Tags: python, django

I want to save the data of cities retrieved by a url into my sqlite database in django.
i want to store data of all cities for every state of a country.
i want to write a script so that all data can be parsed from the url and get stored into my database.
i have paste a url for a state which has id= 5,

http://lab.iamrohit.in/php_ajax_country_state_city_dropdown/api.php?type=getCities&stateId=5

data showing by this url is

```
{"status":"success","tp":1,"msg":"Cities fetched successfully.","result":{"448":"Amarpur","449":"Ara","450":"Araria","451":"Areraj","452":"Asarganj","453":"Aurangabad","454":"Bagaha","455":"Bahadurganj","456":"Bairgania","457":"Bakhtiyarpur","458":"Banka","459":"Banmankhi","460":"Bar Bigha","461":"Barauli","462":"Barauni Oil Township","463":"Barh","464":"Barhiya","465":"Bariapur","466":"Baruni","467":"Begusarai","468":"Behea","469":"Belsand","470":"Bettiah","471":"Bhabua","472":"Bhagalpur","473":"Bhimnagar","474":"Bhojpur","475":"Bihar","476":"Bihar Sharif","477":"Bihariganj","478":"Bikramganj","479":"Birpur","480":"Bodh Gaya","481":"Buxar","482":"Chakia","483":"Chanpatia","484":"Chhapra","485":"Chhatapur","486":"Colgong","487":"Dalsingh
```

this is dictionary type data

i have written this code

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        r=requests.get('http://lab.iamrohit.in/php_ajax_country_state_city_dropdown/api.php?type=getCities&stateId=5')
        data=r.json()
        print "data is here",data['stateid']
        super(Country, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not doing anything with `data` other than printing it.

Comment: How do you want it to be stored? Regardless, the save method doesn't seem to be the right place to be doing this.

Comment: @Selcuk how can i do this

Comment: help me in this how should i write the code

Comment: should i override save method or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't provide model for city, I wrote it myself:

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # id from external source, e.g. 5 from your example
    external_id = models.IntegerField()

    def fetch_cities_from_network(self):
        # Fetching data
        resp = requests.get(
            'http://lab.iamrohit.in/php_ajax_country_state_city_dropdown/'
            'api.php?type=getCities&stateId=%d' % self.external_id
        )

        # Get dictionary with cities
        cities_dict = resp.json()['result']

        # Get dictionary values (city names) and save them into the db
        for city in cities_dict.values():
            City.objects.create(state=self, name=city)


class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And this is how you can use it:

```
state = State.objects.create(name='Some state', external_id=5)
state.fetch_cities_from_network()
```

Comment: can i write this function in views

Comment: thanks bro it helps me a lot.thanks again for your hard work